# Compare two different texts - found the same and different

Tags: linux, python

I want to compare the different two texts. Please check the below details and what I need

The 1st text content:

```
111 xx1
222
333
555
```

The 2nd text content:

```
333
111 xxx
222
888
```

**My questions**

I am searching one command that could print the below results:

**"Update:111 xxx"**

**"Delete:555"**

**"Add:888"**

The most important is that it should show the title "update","Delete","Add".

Comment: You don't have a `444` in your example. Did you mean to say `888`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

which will give

```
1c1
< 111XZ
---
> 111 xxx
3a4
> 888
```

with "<" for data in file 1 and ">" for data in file 2.

Note on output, this is a pseudo `ed` notation.

- `c` means change line
- `a` means append
- `d` means delete (not in sample above)

you can do

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2) |
awk '$1 == "<" {$1=" in file1 } $1== ">" { $1="in file2" } { print } '
```

(just end-of-line after `|`)

Comment: Hello,dear Archemar! Thank you so much for your reply,I had test your method,yes!that is the result what i need.

Comment: Is there other way to show a more concise result，not < and >.thank you so much again

Comment: Hello,dear Archemar

thank you so much for your previous two answers, it is very very important to me.
Now i had updated my new request,this is my last questions

If possible,could you give me more guidances about this

thank you so much agin

Answer (score 0):

You could use `diff` for that. You just have to get used to its output format. There is a handy guide [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm). For something with a GUI there is [meld](http://meldmerge.org/).